# Missing part 'Appdatabase.g.dart' flutter in FLOOR database

Tags: android, flutter, dart, floor

I followed the flutter floor tutorial , Here is my database file

```
import 'package:floor/floor.dart';
import 'package:news_app/database/daos/Userdao.dart';
import 'package:news_app/database/entities/User.dart';
part "AppDatabase.g.dart";


@Database(entities: [User], version: 1)
abstract class ApplicationDatabase extends FloorDatabase {
  Userdao get userDao;
}
```

Here is my dao file,

```
import 'package:floor/floor.dart';
import 'package:news_app/database/entities/User.dart';

@dao
abstract class Userdao{

  @Query("select * from table_user")
  Future<List<User>> getUsersList();

  @insert
  Future<void> insertUser(User user);

}
```

Here is my entity file,

```
import 'package:floor/floor.dart';

@Entity(tableName: 'table_user')
class User{

  @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate: true)
  int id;

  String name;

  String password;

  User({this.id,this.name,this.password});

}


dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
  fluttertoast: 3.1.3
  shared_preferences: 0.5.6
  retrofit: any
  logger: any
  dio: 3.0.8
  http: 0.12.0+4
  json_serializable: any
  floor: ^0.9.0

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  retrofit_generator: any
  build_runner: any
  floor_generator: ^0.9.0
```

Whenever I try to run this command **flutter pub run build_runner build** command I get this error

> [INFO] Running build...
>   [INFO] 1.7s elapsed, 0/1 actions completed.
>   [WARNING] floor_generator:floor_generator on lib/database/ApplicationDatabase.dart:
>   Missing "part 'ApplicationDatabase.g.dart';".

Comment: You have to create a file with name 'AppDatabase.g.dart'.

Comment: import 'dart:async';
 import 'package:path/path.dart';
 import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart' as sqflite;
    
 part "ApplicationDatabase.g.dart";

i have added this code and run the **flutter pub run build_runner build** command and it works.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Are you using the same names of file for database

like **appdatabase.dart**
and **appdatabase.g.dart**

Comment: dude you save millions of minutes of mine

Comment: my file name is `app_database.dart` I have to give `part app_database.g.dart` then run the builder command!. thx

Answer (score 4):

For future readers, To create `database.g.dart` you have to run below command in your terminal,

```
flutter packages pub run build_runner build
```

or to automatically run it, whenever a file changes, use

```
flutter packages pub run build_runner watch
```

To read full procedure visit [floor documentation](https://pub.dev/packages/floor)